# HTML elements overriding each other

Tags: html, css

I am facing a weird problem in my HTML template.

Expected Layout is :

1. Navbar
2. Slider - Text on the slider
3. Some Section.

Result:

Navbar
1. Some Section

1. Slider - Text on the slider - Section on the slider i.e., below the navbar

I am using bootstrap. 
Using 'Developers Tools' I found out that, the slider.js appends some div tags just before any other tags in the body. The whole area is covered by the slider div first. Then comes the navbar and section. Looks like there is no connection between navbar - section and slider.

The existing code looks like this in the browser in developer tools option:

```
<body>
   <div class="slider></div>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="panel">
         <img src="" class="" />
      </div>
   </div>
   <nav>
   </nav>
   <section>
   </section>
</body>
```

Please help me. I am unable to understand.

Thanks.

Comment: a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be helpful..

Comment: Can you please clarify more. you gave the code shown on browser. Can you please give the code you written or expected to be shown on browser. I Agree with T J. Please do

Comment: Most sliders have an option which to be their parent (where to be appended to). Look at your JavaScript if you have set this right. Moreover, your navbar section is outside of the container. Put  <nav> tags right after the opening container tag, add a div with id  #slider after .panel and append the slider to it.

Comment: side note *the div class slider is missing a - "

Comment: Yes I tried the solution u said. But it did not work. It is still the same. In slider.js there is a line ('body').append(tags). tags has all those div tags. I changed it here to $('.slider').append(tags). Also changed  $('.body').prepend(tags) to $('.slider').prepend(tags). But no use. When i put the tags within one container div, the whole html file is getting distorted. But the tags that are getting appended via js file are actually occupying the whole page till the slider ends.